# Where does the Game class come from in the DrawableGameComponent constructor?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, silverlight

I'm making a project to Windows Phone using Silverlight + XNA, but I don't know how I can use the `DrawableGameComponent` because the constructor requires a `Game` class, it looks like this:

Planet.cs

```
class Planet : DrawableGameComponent
{
    public Planet(Game game): base(game){

    {
}
```

but in my first page of Silverlight and XNA project not is a `Game` class it's this:

GamePage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class GamePage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
   ...
}
```

Where do I find the `Game` class to pass into the `DrawableGameComponent` constructor?

Answer (score 1):

XNA + Silverlight projects no longer use the Game class nor do they use the DrawableGameComponent class.

A good article for migrating to XNA + Silverlight: http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/article/migration_guide_moving_to_silverlight_xna

Answer (score 0):

The `DrawableGameComponent` should be instanciated inside a `Game` class.

```
DrawableGameComponent dgc = new DrawableGameComponent(this);
```

As an alternative you could extend the `DrawableGameComponent` with a new one defining your own constructor, but it would lack of sense